# Testing against Java EE 6 API

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven-2, jakarta-ee, junit

I write an addition to JAX-RS and included the Java EE 6 API as a Maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then I have a little test case:

```
  @Test
  public void testIsWriteable() {
    class SpecialViewable extends Viewable {
      public SpecialViewable() {
        super("test");
      }
    }
    FreeMarkerViewProcessor processor = new FreeMarkerViewProcessor(null);
    assertTrue(processor.isWriteable(SpecialViewable.class, null, null,
            MediaType.WILDCARD_TYPE));
  }
```

But I get an error:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType
    ...
```

If I include Jersey as a JAX-RS implementation instead of the Java EE API everything is fine.

Thanks to BalusC's hint I know what I had guessed: Java EE 6 is only an API without method bodies:
[From the java.net blog](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ludo/archive/2007/01/java_ee_5_apis.html)

> You can compile you code with this
>   jar, but of course you cannnot run
>   your application with it since it
>   contains only the Java EE 5 APIs and
>   does not contain any method bodies. If
>   you try to run, you would get this
>   exception:
>
> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ClassFormatError:   Absent
>   Code attribute in method that is not
>   native or abstract in class file
>   javax/mail/Session
>
> In order to execute a Java EE 5
>   application, you'll still need a Java
>   EE 5 container, like for example the
>   GlassFish application server.

I've tried to add Jersy with `test` scope but it didn't work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

How can I test software that depends only on the official Java EE API?

**Solution**

The provider (Jersey) needs to be placed *before* the API (javeee-api) in the pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Here are some related problems with insightful answers: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22java.lang.ClassFormatError%3A+Absent+Code+attribute+in+method+that+is+not+native+or+abstract+in+class+file%22

Comment: I was really gnawing my nails with this problem before I ran into this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Not sure this will solve your problem but GlassFish Embedded provides a Java EE 6 implementation. Add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>glassfish-extras-repository</id>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/extras</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
      <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

It's important to declare the `glassfish-embedded-all` artifact **before** the `javaee-api`.

Comment: Maybe also try with the `jersey-server` artifact (but declare it **before** the `javaee-api`).

Comment: I don't need a full application server like GlassFish, but your hint to place the provider (GlassFish or, in my case, Jersy) before the API was the solution!

Comment: Just a note that the repository URL should actually be http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/

Comment: Is there an embedded glassfish for Java EE 5?

Comment: See http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.main.extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.1.2.2

Comment: The problem with this is that they seem to have exploded a bunch of jars and packaged them back together inside `glassfish-embedded-all`.  You better hope you're using the same slf4j version they packaged in there, because they didn't give a way to exclude what they give you.  There has got to be a better way.

Answer (score 8):

As for me, JBoss' implementation is smaller than the whole Glassfish, so I'm using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jboss-javaee-6.0}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

`<scope>test</scope>` should also do no harm.

Comment: Problem with the JBoss implementation is it has a lot of dependency convergence failures.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that is JSR provider agnostic is

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This allows you to swap Jersey with a different provider. For Glassfish 3.1.2, [it uses `jersey-server` 1.11](http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.2-final.html), which uses `jsr311` version 1.1 according to the jersey pom.

Comment: The question is about unit test, which is not necessarily run in a EE container.