# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/logging/LogDomains when running unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

I'm running a unit test that throws this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/logging/LogDomains
    at com.sun.enterprise.util.ORBManager.<clinit>(ORBManager.java:93)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory.<clinit>(SerialInitContextFactory.java:65)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:46)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:654)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:175)
    myCode
```

My code is this:

```
    try {
        Context c = new InitialContext();  //line that errors
        return (T) c.lookup(name);
    } catch (NamingException ne) {
        log.error(ne.getMessage(), ne);
        throw new RuntimeException(ne);
    }
```

How do I get around this issue?

It seems like this [answer would work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3424908/61624), except for the huge deal breaker I mention in a comment:

> The problem with this is that they seem to have exploded a bunch of jars and packaged them back together inside `glassfish-embedded-all`. You better hope you're using the same slf4j version they packaged in there, because they didn't give a way to exclude what they give you. There has got to be a better way.

FWIW, I'm deploying to Glassfish 3.

Perhaps I need to prevent my unit test from getting to this line.  But it feels weird that I get an `NoClassDefFoundError`  Why is this happening?

Comment: seems like netbeans bug - https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87962 - have lot of info about this

Comment: @Mani I'm not using netbeans.  I'm using intellij idea