# Unable to initialize MockHttpServletRequest in my unit tests

Tags: spring, unit-testing, maven

I am having difficulty getting my unit tests to compile and execute. I am getting the following error.

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE074 no Code attribute specified; class=javax/servlet/ServletInputStream, method=<init>()V, pc=0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:711)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:92)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:314)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:594)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:743)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:711)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:325)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:93)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:170)
    at com.bofa.ecom.olb.pipad.simulator.interceptor.SimulatorInterceptorTest.setup(SimulatorInterceptorTest.java:28)
```

My unit test source code

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class SimulatorInterceptorTest {

  private SimulatorInterceptor simulatorInterceptor;

  private MockHttpServletRequest servletRequest;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    this.simulatorInterceptor = new SimulatorInterceptor();
    this.servletRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes =
        new ServletRequestAttributes(this.servletRequest);
    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(requestAttributes);
  }

  @Test
  public void testTrue() {

  }

}
```

My maven properties are given below:

```
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.springframework.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- DB dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- HTTP Session requires javaee api. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>17.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Don't use the `javaee-web-api` as that is broken. Remove it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424207/testing-against-java-ee-6-api?rq=1

Comment: What should I use? I still get hte same error when I remove it.

Comment: You already have the `javax.servlet-api` dependency which includes those classes. Try the 3.0.1 version as 3.1.0 is JEE7.