# Jersey mockito Exception

Tags: eclipse, junit, jersey, mockito

I have to test a class for REST web services an exception was generated. I use Jersey, Mockito and the IDE is Eclipse, it works fine with Maven command line but not with Eclipse.

class :

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestController {

    @Mock
    Service service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws CertificateException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

In the pom I have:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

When I add:

```java
PowerMockito.mock(Service.class);
```

or

```java
@Mock
Service service;
```

the exception below was thrown:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/ws/rs/core/Response
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    .....
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Please provide a _complete_ .[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @dur the other dependencies are not for jersey or junit tests

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below dependency. Add it after Jersey dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I found similar issue here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424207/testing-against-java-ee-6-api
Please check if it helps