# java ee api is missing in project classpath test

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, netbeans-8

I am trying to create a simple UnitTest for a servlet. Apparently there is some issue with maven (I think) that will impact the build process.

I did some research and apparently this is a known issues. Per my undersetting what need to be done is to change the location of the javaee-web-api dependency in the pom.xml

Unfortunately this solution is not working for me. This is very frustrating since I spending so much time on configuration rather than coding.

Any idea how to solve this problem or maybe some other solutions for testing ?

I am using maven and NetBeans.

Thank you

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: provided means "already on the classpath", perhaps you want to use test instead?

Comment: Can you post the error? What is your project Dynamic Web Module version?

Comment: The 6.0 `javax/javaee-*` artefacts are notorious for this problem. They are OK for compiling but they have been stripped of the content needed to allow them to be used at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Adding org.glassfish.extras dependency solve it.

see this quesion: [Testing against Java EE 6 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424207/testing-against-java-ee-6-api)

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>mavenproject1</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>glassfish-extras-repository</id>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/extras</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```